# Bad permissions for sh

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, zsh

I have problem with `sh` or maybe with privileges.

For example:
I try use `yarn encore dev` and I take an error response:

```
yarn run v1.16.0
$ /media/user/app/node_modules/.bin/encore dev
/bin/sh: 1: /media/user/app/node_modules/.bin/encore: Permission denied
error Command failed with exit code 126.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

when I used something like `sh node_modules/.bin/encore dev` response is still bad

```
node_modules/.bin/encore: 2: node_modules/.bin/encore: /bin: Permission denied
node_modules/.bin/encore: 3: node_modules/.bin/encore: Dockerfile: not found
node_modules/.bin/encore: 4: node_modules/.bin/encore: Dockerfile: not found
node_modules/.bin/encore: 5: node_modules/.bin/encore: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

`./node_modules/.bin/encore dev` also return error:

```
zsh: no access: ./node_modules/.bin/encore
```

---

Privileges:

inside `node_modules/.bin/`

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 user user    40 cze  5 15:00 encore -> ../@symfony/webpack-encore/bin/encore.js
```

app catalog:

```
drwxrwxr-x 744 user user  24576 cze  5 15:01 node_modules
```

All parents catalog `/media/user/app/` until `/` has a 0755.

fstab:

```
UUID=uuuuuuid /media/user/              ext4    errors=remount-ro,auto,exec,rw,user 0       0
```

Anybody know what's wrong or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From [`man 8 mount`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html):

```
user  Allow  an  ordinary user to mount the filesystem. [...] 
      This  option  implies the options noexec, nosuid, and nodev
      (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option
      line user,exec,dev,suid).
```

You need to have `exec` after `user` for it to be effective.

Comment: it works! thank you